# Marking Modifications on a table

Tags: writing, citation-style

I took a table from a paper to show it in my thesis but have to modify the data in a cell (semantically) as well as adding new lines. is it ok to <s>cross out old</s> and *replace with new*? and refer to it in caption like "<s>Modified</s> and **expanded**"

Or what is the way to do this?

Comment: I'd avoid crossing out, since it reduces readability I'd use bold or emphasis for the new data.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano but that is not showing the replaced data.. or is this not necessary and i can refer to the bold/italic data  as "new data or replacement"? Or should i use say bold for replaced data and italic for new (eg. text in added rows)

Comment: I would show the original table unchanged plus have a new table and refer to both in the text. Or don't show the original table at all as it sounds like you reproduced the results and just refer to changed values in the text. Or put the old values that are different in parentheses with a note in the caption and text.